# RAILS_ENV=production vs. rake assets:precompile

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-5

I see different failures for `rake assets:precompile` when I change the value of `RAILS_ENV` to `staging` vs. `production` despite having matching asset setting between the two.

How does the setting of RAILS_ENV affect asset compilation?

Comment: Can you post an example of the failure you get?